# Python variable assigning to another variable error

Tags: python-2.7, variables

So I am making a program to print the max element of a list,

```
arr=[1,2,41,6,9,8,5]
c=0
def findmax(x,y):
    if(x>y):
        global c=x
    else:
        global c=y

for x in range(0,len(arr)):
    findmax(c,arr[x])

print(c)
```

When I try to run the program, it says `error: invald syntax line 5 global c=x` pointing to the = sign
How do I fix it?

Comment: You can not write `global x = y`, you can only write `global x` and then later `x = y`.

Comment: why not simply do: `max(arr)` ? you should declare a global in the beginning of the function and then you can use it later on. Plenty of examples over the web.

Comment: Except for that, using a `global` us usually a huge **antipattern**. If you see it, you should definitely put some effort in rethinking your code.

Answer (score 2):

Before using a global variable, you have to declare that the variable is global

```
arr=[1,2,41,6,9,8,5]
c=0
def findmax(x,y):
    if(x>y):
        global c
        c=x
    else:
        global c
        c=y

for x in range(0,len(arr)):
    findmax(c,arr[x])

print(c)
```

or you can just declare a global variable once as

```
arr=[1,2,41,6,9,8,5]
c=0
def findmax(x,y):
    global c
    if(x>y):
        c=x
    else:
        c=y

for x in range(0,len(arr)):
    findmax(c,arr[x])

print(c)
```

Comment: Why do you declare `global c` twice?

Comment: Because every time it calls a function, only one of the code block will be executed (either if or else).

Comment: If you're going to do it anyways (regardless if the if/else is getting executed) why not do it once in the beginning? do you like duplicated code ? if the variable name changes later, now you have to change it in two places instead of one (just an example of why it's bad practice).

Comment: True @alfasin. I agree it's a bad practice. that's why I added the modified code snippet after your first comment

Answer (score 1):

The following line is not correct:

```
global x = y
```

instead you have to first write

```
global x
```

then you are allowed to assign `x`.